# Android: Error when generating the APP bundle (AAB) - ionic Angular

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am using IONIC - ANGULAR - CORDOBA

[ionic-angular-cordoba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLGv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj3p2.png)
At the moment of generating the APP bundle (AAB) I have the following error:

gradlew bundle
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :app
> An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\angular\proyectos\opticks\trunk\latin-pedidos-offline\mobile\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 112
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Unable to determine Android SDK directory.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

BUILD FAILED in 12s

Can someone help me, Thanks!

Comment: As the error say: did you add compileSdkVersion to your build.gradle?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that I can't find the place where I have to add it!!!.
 Can you help me ?

Comment: In android > variables.gradle you'll have `ext { ... }` so just put your preferrable compileSDK value, like: `ext { compileSdkVersion = 30 }` (there will be other properties there, just add compile version to your next line in ext).